# Saving an rendered animation again, without rerendering

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, saving

So I have made an animation, but when the render was finished, it didn't output the file, is there any sort of way to save the animation again, without having to rerender?

Comment: Does F11 or Ctrl+F11 bring up the animation? If so, you might be able to save from there.

Comment: @RonJensen that works, but only in Blender the actual file for it only goes about a quarter of the animation.